# SSIS Package Execution from Visual Studio

Tags: ssis

I am writing code to exceute SSIS package from Visual Studio , everything works fine , but when i created a setup (MSI file) for this solution , it is not able to run on other machines. Is it not able to create Application object from which we execute SSIS package. Is there any DLL i can add in my solution so that it will execute on other machines?

Answer (score 1):

You need a SQL Server installation on target machine. More exactly, you need the common elements from the SQL binaries, not the SSIS service itself.

There is no DLL you can add: an SSIS package is not a standalone executable.

[A similar question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711991/dts-e-productleveltoolow-error-when-running-package-from-command-line/4712089#4712089)